# vuforia for Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)

Tags: ios6

I have a specific problem about iOS generation vuforia sdk, as this sdk has the sample app, i want to integrate its sample app to my existing app which is developed base on ARC, there are problem caused by Automatic Reference Counting (ARC).

and vuforia sdk and its sample app is developed based non-ARC.

any advice or solution can you give me to convert your sample app into one version with ARC ?

I tried to modified and keep the statement getting rid of "release" or "autorelease" term , problem is still unsolved

Comment: Did you try "Edit -> Refactor -> Convert to Objective-C ARC..." in Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

you have to:

Add the Vuforia SDK to an existing app.

add ARCommon folder to your source.

Link to the include headers (e.g. ../vuforia/build/include)

Link to the library path (e.g. ../vuforia/build/lib/arm)

Add libQcar to linked libraries in Build phases of your target.

**DISABLE ARC** on the included files to they can use retain/release. (Project:Go to Build Phases> Compile Sources and set the Compiler Flags "-fno-objc-arc")

Alter files that refer to the QcarUtils.h to a .mm file.